# No matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(std::string*, long long unsigned int)'

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, malloc, ofstream

So I was playing around a bit with file ofstream and ifstream and got stuck into a compiler problem that I just simply don't know what it means...

Let's start.

I have the following class:

```
class FS{
    public:
        string name;
        long long int size;
        long long int freeBlocks;
        long long int usedBlocks = 0;
        int blocksize = 128;
        vector<FS_File> file_list;
        char * ptr;                      //This is a malloc pointer
        void saveTo(ofstream& of); 
        void openFrom(ifstream& inf); 
    };
```

The problem occurs in the ***saveTo()*** function:

```
void FS::saveTo(ofstream& of){ 
  of.write(&name, sizeof(name)); 
  of.write(&size, sizeof(size));
  of.write(&freeBlocks, sizeof(freeBlocks)); 
  of.write(&usedBlocks, sizeof(usedBlocks)); 
  of.write(&blocksize, sizeof(blocksize)); 
  of.write(&file_list, sizeof(file_list));
  of.write((char *)&ptr, sizeof(ptr));
}
```

The compiler gives me the next error:

```
functions.cpp   In member function 'void FS::saveTo(std::ofstream&)':


    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(std::string*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(long long int*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(long long int*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(long long int*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(int*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(std::vector<FS_File>*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::read(std::string*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::read(long long int*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::read(long long int*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::read(long long int*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::read(int*, long long unsigned int)'

    [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::read(std::vector<FS_File>*, long long unsigned int)'
```

Whenever I try to call the next code:

```
ofstream outfile;
string filename = curFS.name + ".dat";
outfile.open(filename, ios::binary | ios::out);
curFS.save(outfile);
outfile.close();
```

I've tried a few things, but nothing has worked...

***What does the compiler error means?
How can I solve it?***

Comment: `of.write(&name, sizeof(name));` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Writing a `std::string` by address to a file stream will only ultimately result in nonsense. Writing that `std::vector` object by address isn't going to bode well either. Nor will writing a `char*` *by address*. Just think about what is actually being written to the disk file in all of those cases. And, the error messages mean *exactly* what they say. Look at the proper prototype for [`std::basic_ostream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write). How many of your by-address writes match that type. Remember, C++ is *strongly* typed.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages are self explanatory. `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` are streams of `char` data, but you are trying to read/write data using pointers to non-`char` types. There are no overloads of the `write()` and `read()` methods for non-`char` pointers.

For POD types, you can simply type cast your pointers to `char*`.

That won't work for non-POD types, like `std::string` and `std::vector`. For those types, you need to *marshal* the data instead.

Try something more like this instead:

```
void FS::saveTo(ofstream& of)
{
    // std::string needs to be marshaled...
    size_t value = name.size();
    of.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
    of.write(name.c_str(), value);

    // POD types can be written as-is...
    of.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
    of.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&freeBlocks), sizeof(freeBlocks));
    of.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&usedBlocks), sizeof(usedBlocks));
    of.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&blocksize), sizeof(blocksize));

    // std::vector needs to be marshaled...
    value = file_list.size();
    of.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < value; ++i) {
        // write file_list[i] to the stream as needed...
    }

    // dynamic data needs to be marshaled...
    value = strlen(ptr); // or whatever the actual allocated size is...
    of.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
    of.write(ptr, value);
}

void FS::openFrom(ifstream& inf)
{
    size_t value;

    // std::string needs to be marshaled...
    inf.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
    name.resize(value);
    inf.read(&name[0], value);

    // POD types can be read as-is...
    inf.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
    inf.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&freeBlocks), sizeof(freeBlocks));
    inf.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&usedBlocks), sizeof(usedBlocks));
    inf.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&blocksize), sizeof(blocksize));

    // std::vector needs to be marshaled...
    inf.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
    file_list.resize(value);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < value; ++i) {
        // read file_list[i] from stream as needed...
    }

    // dynamic data needs to be marshaled...
    inf.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
    free(ptr);
    ptr = (char*) malloc(value+1);
    inf.read(ptr, value);
    ptr[value] = '\0';
}
```

Just be sure to always open the streams with the `std::ios_base::binary` flag enabled. To help ensure that, I would suggest passing the filename to `saveTo()`/`openFrom()` instead of user-supplied streams:

```
void FS::saveTo(const string& filename)
{
    ofstream outfile(filename, ios::binary);
    saveTo(outfile);
}

void FS::openFrom(const string& filename)
{
    ifstream infile(filename, ios::binary);
    openFrom(infile);
}
```

```
curFS.saveTo(curFS.name + ".dat");
```

```
curFS.openFrom(curFS.name + ".dat");
```

Comment: This is literally the fix for my problem, but there's one little problem. 

First, I have a question... Does this sol reads the information in the openFrom function and loads it back into the class?

If it does:
Let's say I create the  .dat file and shutdown the program that I used to create the file. Now I open another instance and tell it to open the .dat file. It does read the file, but when I try to access it doesn't have any information at all.

If it doesn't, how do I load the info back in?

Sorry for all the questions that I made, but it's literally the first time I use this.

Comment: @AlanMaldonado "*Does this sol reads the information in the openFrom function and loads it back into the class?*" - yes. "*It does read the file, but when I try to access it doesn't have any information at all*" - then you are either not loading the data correctly, or you are calling `openFrom()`
on the wrong `FS` object, or an invalid object. Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that is not working for you as expected.